# Popover UI in Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, user-interface, osx-snow-leopard

How can I get [popover](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSPopover_Class/Reference/Reference.html)-like behavior in Snow Leopard?

[image]

`NSPopover` is only available in Lion, but are there any good third party libraries to get similar behavior in 10.6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Matt Gemmell's MAAttachedWindow. You can find it on this page:

http://mattgemmell.com/source/

Matt provides a link to a project using this with a NSStatusItem; it probably wouldn't be too much of a stretch to modify it to work with whatever you've got in mind.